# Android N : how can i migrate from Android SDK API to Android ICU API

Tags: icu4j, android-7.0-nougat

I was confused related `ICU4J` , if i want to upgrade my application version to Support `Android N` . How can i migrate from previous Android SDK to Android ICU API . For Example if i have used Calendar in my Application Using `java.util.Calendar` , will i implement that again with Android ICU API ? or there is shortest way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't have to implement that again for android N. but just change way of use.

explained in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/preview/features/icu4j-framework.html)

**Migrating to android.icu APIs from other Android SDK APIs**

use `android.icu.util.Calendar` instead of `java.util.Calendar`

---

*for support older version then Android N you have to add `ICU4J libraries`*

Comment: Where can I find this "ICU4J libraries" is there any support library to include ?

Answer (score 0):

While migrating from icu4j to android N. You don't have to implement it again in android N. But you need to **change only the imports & remove the ICU4J from your external library** as per the document.

If you are already using the ICU4J APIs in your app, and the `android.icu` APIs meet your requirements, **then migrating to the framework APIs requires you to change your Java imports from `com.ibm.icu` to `android.icu`.**

- You may then remove your own copy of ICU4J files from the APK.

When you migrating from ICU4J to android N please note below point.

> Note:

- The ICU4J framework APIs use the `android.icu` namespace instead of
  `com.ibm.icu`.
- This is to avoid namespace conflicts in APKs that contain their own
  com.ibm.icu libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Like all new APIs, if you want you app to work on earlier versions of Android you should not use them (unless you protect the calls behind version checks).

If you only intend to target the N release, then you can use the android.icu ICU4J APIs.

Comment: What the reason to develop app only for android N and higher ? If my min sdk=14 how can I use icu classes ? Maybe there is some support library with icu package?